# BigInteger unsigned left or right shift

Tags: java, biginteger, bit-shift

I am reimplementing a function using BigInteger in place in int. Now there is step

```
h = n >>> log2n--
```

But I am facing trouble here. In original code h, n, log2n all are int type, if I set h, n, and log2n to BigInteger what will be the equivalent expression of the above code? How do I perform an unsigned right shift (>>>) in BigInteger?

Edit:
The code block is :

```
int log2n = 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
    int h = 0, shift = 0, high = 1;

    while (h != n)
    {
        shift += h;
        h = n >>> log2n--;
        int len = high;
        high = (h & 1) == 1 ? h : h - 1;
        len = (high - len) / 2;

        if (len > 0)
        {
            p = p.multiply(product(len));
            r = r.multiply(p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know Java doesn't have operator overloading, right?

Comment: Yes. I am not saying about operator overloading. Isn't there any turn around way or method or algorithm to find unsigned shift operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from the Java docs:

> The unsigned right shift operator
>   (>>>) is omitted, as this operation
>   makes little sense in combination with
>   the "infinite word size" abstraction
>   provided by this class.

An 32-bit integer representation of -1 is (in binary)

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

If you use the signed right-shift operator (`>>`) on this, you'll get

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

i.e. the same thing.  If you use the unsigned right-shift operator on this, shifting by 1, you'll get

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111.
```

But BigInteger has an unlimited length.  The representation of -1 in a BigInteger is theoretically

```
11111111 111... infinite 1s here..... 11111111
```

The unsigned right-shift operator would imply that you were putting a 0 at the leftmost point - which is at infinity.  Since this makes little sense, the operator is omitted.

As regards your actual code, what you need to do now depends on what the surrounding code is doing and why an unsigned shift was chosen for the original code.  Something like

```
n.negate().shiftRight(log2n)
```

*might* work, but it all depends on the circumstances.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a solution, it's awful, but it works:

```
public BigInteger srl(BigInteger l, int width, int shiftBy) {
    if (l.signum() >= 0)
        return l.shiftRight(shiftBy);
    BigInteger opener = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(width + 1);
    BigInteger opened = l.subtract(opener);
    BigInteger mask = opener.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).shiftRight(shiftBy + 1);
    BigInteger res = opened.shiftRight(shiftBy).and(mask);
    return res;
}
```

The case that your integer is positive is trivial, as shiftRight will return the correct result anyway. But for negative numbers this gets tricky. The negate version mentioned earlier does not work as -1 in BigInteger negated is 1. Shift it and you have 0. But you need to know what the width of your BigInteger is. You then basically force the BigInteger to have at least width+1 bits by subtracting an opener. Then you perform the shifting, and mask away the extra bit that you introduced. It doesn't really matter what opener you use, as long as it doesn't alter the lower bits.

How the opener works:

The BigInteger implementation does only store the highest 0 position for negative numbers. A -3 is represented as:

```
1111_1111_1111_1111_1101
```

But only some bits are stored, I marked the others as X.

```
XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XX01
```

Shifting to the right does nothing as there are always 1's coming from the left. So the idea is to substract a 1 to generate a 0 outside of the width that you are interested in. Assuming you care about the lowest twelve bit:

```
XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXX_XX01
-    0001_0000_0000_0000
========================
XXXX_XXX0_1111_1111_1101
```

This forced the generation of real 1s. You then shift right by lets say 5.

```
XXXX_XXX0_1111_1111_1101
>>5   XXXX_XXX0_1111_111
```

And then mask it:

```
XXXX_XXX0_1111_111
0000_0000_1111_111
```

And therewith receive the correct result:

```
0000_0000_1111_111
```

So the introduction of the zero forced the BigInteger implementation to update the stored 0 position to a width that is higher than the one you are interested in and forced the creation of stored 1s.

Comment: fyi the question was asked 2 years back and an answer accepted

Comment: i still don't understand why you subtract some 2^(width+1) from l. isn't it enough to just shift and then mask away the new bits?

Comment: I added some explanation, does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

The BigInteger class has the following operations

```
 BigInteger     shiftLeft(int n)

 BigInteger     shiftRight(int n)
```

Comment: @Tapas: no they are not, check out the Javadocs for the `BigInteger` class.